# Google drive does not load preview of images

Tags: google-drive

I can download my pictures from Google drive but I cannot preview them. It keeps loading endlessly. The preview works in my phone and the format of the images is jpg, so nothing funny there.

Any idea why it does not load preview? Is it because I have more than 100Gb used?
[image]